# is there a difference between these two statements with parenthesis and without?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic

Is there a difference between these two statements? one uses parenthesis, while the other doesn't.

$(\exists x\in \mathbb{R}, x>5) \Rightarrow (\forall y \in \mathbb{R}, y>-100)$

is it the same as

$\exists x\in \mathbb{R}, x>5 \Rightarrow \forall y \in \mathbb{R}, y>-100$

1. Are these two equivalent?
2. are both false-statements?

Comment: Yes, they are equivalent.  They are true because there ARE numbers that are greater -100.

Comment: it doesn't say "there ARE numbers greater than -100". It says "ALL real numbers are greater than -100"
 
I do understand that the first statement is a false-statement since T => F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a matter of convention whether the missing parentheses in $\exists x, P \Rightarrow \forall y, Q$ should be inserted to give $(\exists x, P) \Rightarrow (\forall y, Q)$ or to give $\exists x, (P \Rightarrow (\forall y, Q))$. The former reading is most common in the mathematical logic literature, but the latter reading agrees with the usual conventions for the $\lambda$-calculus and has been adopted in many mechanized theorem-proving systems such as HOL or Coq.

In the case in point, the two readings are not equivalent:

In $(\exists x\in \mathbb{R}, x>5) \Rightarrow (\forall y \in \mathbb{R}, y>-100)$, the left-hand side of the implication is true (e.g., take $x = 6)$ while the right-hand side is false (e.g., take $y = -100$). So the overall predicate is false.

However, in $\exists x\in \mathbb{R}, (x>5  \Rightarrow (\forall y \in \mathbb{R}, y>-100))$, we can take $x = 5$, to make $x > 5$ false and hence the overall predicate is true, since a false statement implies any other statement and we can find an $x$ that falsifies $x > 5$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation.

So, in the second statement (without parenthesis) we cannot determine if it is True or False (because it depends on the x value).

correct?

Comment: No. I am sorry if I was unclear: there is an $x \in \Bbb{R}$ that makes $x > 5 \Rightarrow \ldots$ true, so $\exists x \in \Bbb{R}(x > 5 \Rightarrow \ldots)$ is true.